# Travis CI issue: Couldn't find the specified scheme in the mentioned workspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci

This build failure issue is occurring in case of cocoapads caching, meaning if I add command to cache cocoapods in yml file, the build breaks on travis otherwise it works just as fine. And the build failure issue i get everytime is "The workspace named "some_workspace" does not contain a scheme named "some_scheme". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace."

I think something is misconfigured with my project's xcscheme data or something which only makes schemes available if "pod install" command runs and activates the xcworkspace.

**Please note that all my xcode schemes are already shared!**

Thanks in advance for all the help I can get on this concerned issue.

Answer (score 1):

Great thanks to Travis support team, because of their help and support only I was able to resolve my concerned issue. The issue was due to pods cache configuration which was resolved by introducing pod install command in before_install clause, which I guess somehow helps the CI builder in picking in the cached pod files from last build and to execute the build.